# Is it really Refused Parent Bequest code smell?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

Martin Fowler defined Refused parent bequest as Subclasses get to inherit the methods and data of their parents. But what if they don't want or need what they are given? They are given all these great gifts and pick just a few to play with.
Now my question is, in the following code the child class overrides only on method of the parent class. So, is it refused parent bequest?

```
public class BinaryChop extends ColumnFixture {

public int key, array[];
// The execute method is overriden 
public void execute() {
    int empty[] = {};
    if (array==null) array=empty;
}

public int result() {
    return chopFriday(key, array) ;
}

public int mon() {return chopMonday(key, array);}
public int tue() {return chopTuesday(key, array);}
public int wed() {return chopWednesday(key, array);}
public int thr() {return chopThursday(key, array);}
public int fri() {return chopFriday(key, array);}

int chopMonday (int key, int array[]) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = array.length-1;
    while (min<=max) {
        int probe = (min+max)/2;
        if (key == array[probe]) {
            return probe;
        } else if (key > array[probe]) {
            min = probe+1;
        } else {
            max = probe-1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
.......
}
```

Besides, Martin Fowler mentioned that "The smell of refused bequest is much stronger if the subclass is reusing behavior but does not want to support the interface of the superclass." Can anyone explain it to me? Does it mean that the overriden method perform something similar to the parent's class method?

Answer (score 1):

Overriding a method in subclass serve the purpose and it is not an instance of refused bequest smell.

What Fowler meant by stating "...does not want to support the interface of the superclass" is that a subclass rejecting the interface declared by the superclass (for example, overriding a method from a superclass and returning `NotSupportedException` or even `0` or `null`).

A detailed explanation could be found in *Broken Hierarchy* design smell in [Refactoring for software design smells](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0128013974) book.